# Cannot Embed Twitter Timeline in Cordova App

Tags: javascript, cordova, twitter, sapui5

I am having an issue integrating the Twitter Widget in a Cordova app. I am trying to wrap a UI5 application with the Twitter Widget in a Cordova container.

I have the Twitter Widget successfully working on browser, but when I make an iOS build of this app using Cordova, only the hashtag displays (and not the live tweets).

Please find the source code below in one of my .view.js files. Has anyone else run into this issue and found a solution ?

```
var tweets = new sap.ui.core.HTML();
tweets.setContent("<a class=\"twitter-timeline\" href=\"https://twitter.com/hashtag/HASHTAGHERE\" data-widget-id=\"IDHERE\">HASHTAGHERE</a> <script>!function(d,s,id) { var js,fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+\"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,\"script\",\"twitter-wjs\");</script>");
```

Comment: I think you need the InAppBrowser phonegap plugin to make this work